# Invalid parameter: PlatformPrincipal not valid

Tags: ios, terraform, apple-push-notifications, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create the aws sns ios push notification platform application using terraform. I am getting the following error

```
 Error creating SNS platform application: InvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: PlatformPrincipal not valid.
```

Below is my terraform code

```
resource "aws_sns_platform_application" "apns_application" {
  name                = var.ios_application_name
  platform            = var.ios_platform
  platform_credential = var.ios_key
  platform_principal  = filebase64("${path.module}/TestAPNS.p12")
}
```

Any suggestions how can I solve this issue. Currently the certificate is generated for the sandbox environment.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation appears that it is looking for a certificate, not a base64'd certificate. (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sns_platform_application)

Have you tried

```
  platform_principal  = file("${path.module}/TestAPNS.p12")
```

?

Comment: Yes I tried with it. I get the following error. Call to function "file" failed: contents of ./TestAPNS.p12 are not valid UTF-8; use the filebase64 function to obtain the Base64 encoded contents or the other file functions (e.g. filemd5, filesha256) to obtain file hashing results instead.

Comment: ok, So I resolve the issue. I generated the private and public keys using the openssl from .p12 certificate and now it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to work with your `.p12` file using this handy provider: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/bendrucker/pkcs12/latest/docs/data-sources/archive

```
data "pkcs12_archive" "apns_certificate" {
  archive  = filebase64("${path.root}/TestAPNS.p12")
  password = var.apns_certificate_password
}

resource "aws_sns_platform_application" "apns_application" {
  name                = "${var.env}-${var.sns_platform_name}-APN"
  platform            = "APNS"
  platform_credential = data.pkcs12_archive.apns_certificate.private_key
  platform_principal  = data.pkcs12_archive.apns_certificate.certificate
}
```